# How do I build latest Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I've tried to build Tycho now for a couple of hours and just can't get it to work. I've followed these instructions:

https://docs.sonatype.org/display/TYCHO/BuildingTycho

So, I've downloaded Eclipse 3.6RC2 and Delta-packs linked from this instruction (is it for 3.5 only?):

`http:// (remove space) aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/06/using-deltapack-in-eclipse-35.html`

I've added the DeltaPack to the TargetPlatform inside of the Eclipse-installation.

I've installed Maven: Apache Maven 3.0-beta-1 (r935667; 2010-04-19 19:00:39+0200)

I can run the first bootstrap of the build, but the second fails:
`mvn clean install -e -V -Pbootstrap-2 -Dtycho.targetPlatform=$TYCHO_TARGET_PLATFORM`

```
ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Could not resolve plugin org.eclipse.core.net.linux.x86_null -> [Help 1]
```

I've tried different stuff, I built an older revision against 3.5 as in this blogpost:
`http:// (remove space) divby0.blogspot.com/2010/03/im-in-love-with-tycho-08-and-maven-3.html`

and that actually built a running maven, but that version then can't find the tycho plugin:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.version.PluginVersionResolutionException: Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.tycho:maven-tycho-plugin' from the repositories [local (/Users/viktor/.m2/repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository
```

I thought that the point was that the plugin was going to build in when I had built a Tycho-dist…?

Sorry about the links, stackoverflows spam-protection doesn't let me post more than one url yet

Comment: This question is about an ancient version of Tycho - the described problems no longer occur.

Answer (score 0):

The Tycho documentation is pretty bad, to set the record straight, Tycho is included in the Maven repositories by default now; declaring it in your POM will automatically download it and allow you to use it.

To cut to the chase, this is all you have to put in your Maven POM to use Tycho, and then next time Maven uses this POM for a project, it will get Tycho if you don't already have it and use it for the build. At the time of this writing, 0.12.0 is the latest stable release.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now, say, you would like to use an "unstable" Tycho, like `<version>0.13.0</version>`. Then you would want to change the version number in the plugin to the appropriate value, and then add this (The latest Tycho repository) to your POM:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-release</id>
        <url>http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/sonatype-public-grid
        </url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

That simple.

Answer (score 0):

With the move to eclipse.org, we also invested in better documentation for contributors:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Developing_Tycho
- http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Contributor_Guide